# Protect any unwanted operation by Windows in dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, ntfs

I have both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 on different partitions on my hard drive. There is a ntfs partition accessible to the two OSes.

I have almost always been using Ubuntu, and haven't used Windows 7 for more than a year.
From my experiences, I expect that when I reboot into Windows 7,  Windows 7 will take a while and several reboots to update and configure itself.

I heard from another person who also has dual boot that his ntfs partition shared between the two OSes was wiped out during Windows automatically updating itself. So I wonder what I can do to protect that from happening?

- I will make a copy of important data on my hard drive.
- How can I make the ntfs partition shared between the two OSes to be read-only before rebooting into Windows 7, to protect it from being overwritten?
- How can I check, control and choose what updates Windows 7 will do to itself, when I rebooting into Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows 7 will only update if it has pending updates stored in it. As soon as that ends, you can stop Windows Update manually.

Comment: how can I stop Windows 7 from searching online for available updates?

Comment: Try [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-automatic-updating-on-off#turn-automatic-updating-on-off=windows-7).